# What are the options in create-react-app for dealing with rest-syntax issues in Edge?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, spread-syntax

I have a react app based on `create-react-app` that makes much use of object rest/spread syntax as defined [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread). This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but crashes Edge < 79.

I have tried adding the `react-app-polyfill` and `core-js` imports, as recommended in the docs. These fix a few other issues, but don't touch this syntax problem.

Examples of the problem code:

```
const { x, y, ...rest} = props;
const newprops = {...rest, z:1 }
```

Is there any way of handling this without ejecting the project?